# TurboTax had me file for a 1040 instead of a 1040NR. Is there a way I can change this?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, turbotax

It's my first time filing for a US tax return. I used TurboTax, filled up all the necessary information, and I got the result showing a form 1040, which means I got zero amount. I am from the Philippines, so I should have had a 1040NR. Is there away I can edit or cancel the TurboTax result?

Comment: The fact that you are form the Philippines doesn't necessary mean you should file Form 1040NR.  Take a look at https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/determining-alien-tax-status.

Answer (score 1):

TurboTax does not support 1040NR but instead links with SprinTax which does. Here's the [FAQ](https://ttlc.intuit.com/community/forms/help/does-turbotax-handle-form-1040nr-for-nonresident-aliens/00/26295) which was updated on January 13, 2020:

> **Does TurboTax handle Form 1040NR for nonresident aliens?**
>
> TurboTax doesn't support Form 1040NR: U.S. Nonresident Alien Income
>   Tax Return, but we have a partnership with Sprintax offering a
>   nonresident tax filing solution to our TurboTax customers.